# How do I specifiy where results will be stored when performing a simulation?

Tags: r, simulation

I am currently carrying out the simulation below. I have done it once and was hoping to repeat it a 100 times. However , I get the same results under the one simulation run as in the 100 one. I struggle with knowing where or how the for-loop results are stored. I am a bigginner in R so completely clueless as to what is wrong with my code below.

```
#### Repeating the simulation for 100 times
nsims= 100
incomes_priv = matrix(NA, 36, nsims)# store priv income results
incomes_pub=matrix(NA,36, nsims)#to store pub income results
savings_priv= matrix(NA, 36, nsims)#to store savings from priv
savings_public=matrix(NA,36 ,nsims)#to store savings from pub

set.seed(500)

for (j in 1:nsims){{
  print(j)

  for(i in 1:36){incomes_pub100= rnorm(36 ,29200, 10000)
  income_priv100=rnorm(36,25500, 17000)
    saved_pub100=prop.saved *income_pub100
    saved_pri100=prop.saved *income_priv100}


  incomes_pri <- incomes_priv100
  incomes_pub<- income_pub100
  savings_priv <- saved_pri100
  savings_pub<- saved_pub100
}
```

Comment: I get what you are trying to do, but why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: I think there is a simpler way to do this, but what is your end goal? You may be able to simplify the entire process

Comment: also `prop.saved` is not called on before the loop

Comment: Also to answer your question, the results are stored in `incomes_pri`, `incomes_pub`, `savings_priv`, and `savings_pub`, but it is over-writing the original matrix into a vector

Answer (score 2):

You aren't indexing where in these matrices you want the results stored, so you are overwriting them each time.  Try:

```
#### Repeating the simulation for 100 times
nsims          = 100
incomes_priv   = matrix(NA, 36, nsims)  # store priv income results
incomes_pub    = matrix(NA, 36, nsims)  # to store pub income results
savings_priv   = matrix(NA, 36, nsims)  # to store savings from priv
savings_pub    = matrix(NA, 36, nsims)  # to store savings from pub
prop.saved     = .1

set.seed(500)

for(j in 1:nsims){
  print(j)

  for(i in 1:36){
    income_pub100  = rnorm(1, 29200, 10000) 
    income_priv100 = rnorm(1, 25500, 17000)
    saved_pub100   = prop.saved *income_pub100
    saved_pri100   = prop.saved *income_priv100

    incomes_priv[i,j] <- income_priv100
    incomes_pub[i,j]  <- income_pub100
    savings_priv[i,j] <- saved_pri100
    savings_pub[i,j]  <- saved_pub100
  }
}
```

The key is I added `[i,j]` to indicate *where* in each matrix the result should be stored.  That way, you aren't overwriting the matrix on each pass through the loop.  (I've also cleaned up a lot of the code, e.g. mismatched braces, and made the code better ordered visually.)

Comment: Monica , thank you for the help. I am now getting an error which says : number of items is not a multiple of replacement length .

Comment: @Lorato, "gung" not "Monica". To learn about why I've changed my username & avatar, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217536/gung-reinstate-monica?tab=profile).

Comment: For the record, I didn't run this code, it's rather inefficient & there were lots of errors.  I just fixed the things that were obvious, keeping the code to the structure you are presumably comfortable with. The big issue, regarding your explicit question, is that you didn't have subscripts (`[i,j]`), so you were overwriting the variables on each iteration. More sensible code is given by @akash87.  I'll try running this to see if I can identify the problem.

Comment: So, the first think I notice is that `prop.saved` is not defined anywhere here.  (It's presumably in code you didn't copy into the Q.  I'll just define it as `.1`.

Comment: Thank you , I think the main problem is that I have no idea what I am doing haha

Comment: Yeah, that's what it's like when you try it the first time.

Comment: You had a number of variables w/ different names in different places, & an extra curly brace.  I think it should run now.

Comment: You're welcome, @Lorato. If you're satisfied, you can 'accept' one of the answers by clicking the check mark / tick to its left under the vote total. Either is fine.  From an R coding perspective, the other answer is better.  I just tried to mirror the way you were already doing it.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify your code I would do

```
nr <- 36
nsims <- 100
incomes_priv <- matrix(rnorm(nr*nsims, 29200, 10000), nr, nsims)
incomes_pub  <- matrix(rnorm(nr*nsims, 25500, 17000), nr, nsims)
savings_priv <- prop.saved * incomes_priv
savings_pub  <- prop.saved * incomes_pub
```

This should result in something close. Not sure why you need to iterate one value/one column at a time when you can randomly generate your values all at once and put them in a matrix accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @akash87. I am mainly following class notes in which code is written that way. Not yet able to use R without a lot of regurgitating the notes.